# Regex for repeated sub strings in a lengthy string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string which has repeated values "There are 14 no of pigs and 11 no of cows and many more".Here in this string I want to find the substring starting with number and ending with animal names and replace with some other string.

tried with this. But it selects complete string
(\b\d+.* (pig|cow|chicken)s?\b) And not the individual substrings.

Comment: Add `?` after `.*` - https://regex101.com/r/9jS3OE/1

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew